# Can there be an abelian group $G$ where $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} nG$ is not divisible?

Tags: group-theory, model-theory

I heard a talk yesterday on MacIntyre's theorems, which involved a decomposition of ($\omega$-stable) groups into a divisible part and a bounded exponent part.  Apparently there is a result of Kaplansky that all abelian groups have a maximal divisible part.

Clearly, if $D$ is a divisible subgroup, then $D=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} nD\subseteq \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} nG$.  Under certain hypotheses (e.g. $\omega$-saturation of the group), it's easy to show that this subset relation is actually equality.  I was told that some hypothesis is necessary to guarantee that, which made me wonder:

> Is there an abelian group $G$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} nG$ is not divisible?

So, there would have to be an element $x$ which is "divisible" (in that you can divide $x$ by $n$ for every $n>0$, since $x\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}nG$), but in order to divide it by $n$, the result must *not* be divisible (i.e. for some $n$, and every $y$, if $ny=x$, then $y$ is not "divisible").

Is such a group possible?

Comment: Perhaps you can define an abelian group $G$ with generators $t$ and $x_k$ for $k>1$ with $2t=0$ and $kx_k=t$ for all $k$. Then $\cap_{n \in {\mathbb N}}nG = \langle t \rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $G$ by the abelian group presentation $\langle t, x_k\,(k>1) \mid
2t=0,\,kx_k=t\,(k>1)\rangle$. Then $\cap_{n \in {\mathbb N}} \,nG = \langle t \rangle$, a group of order $2$, which is not divisible.

Comment: I'm wondering about the following: If I'm not mistaken, the group $A := \bigcap_n nG$ is divisible if $G$ is torsion-free. Now, if the relation $2t=0$ in your group is removed, $G$ is torsion-free and $A$ is still the cyclic group $\langle t\rangle$ and hence not divisible. Am I missing something ? (cont)

Comment: For the sake of completeness I include my reasoning why $A$ is divisible if $G$ is torsion-free: Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $f: G \to G$ be multiplication by $m$. Then 

$$\bigcap_n nG \subseteq \bigcap_{m | n} nG = \bigcap_n (mn)G = \bigcap_n f(nG) = f(\bigcap_n nG) = m \bigcap_n nG \subseteq \bigcap_n nG$$
where $f$ commutes with the intersection because it's injective. Thus $mA=A$ for all $m$.

Comment: I don't think $G$ would be torsion-free if you remove $2t=0$. We still have $2x_2 = 4x_4 = t$, which gives $2(x_2 - 2x_4) = 0$. Hence $x_2 - 2x_4$ will have a finite order.

Comment: @Levon: OK, this is the point I was missing. Thank you very much.